# Insert data to Sesame Database using SQL queries

Tags: sql, sesame

I would like to know whether is possible to add normal data to a Sesame Database using SQL queries and retrieve them through SQL queries..??

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean adding new tables to the Sesame store so that you can store non-RDF data as well? If you use Sesame's RDBMS store, then it could be possible. But it is probably not such a good idea, because it would be very easy to mess up Sesame's internal schema and put the store into an inconsistent state.

If you use Sesame's native store, then it's not possible.